# How to inform ubuntu of the actual graphic card I have?

Tags: radeon, gpu-driver

In 4 different ubuntu flavors (mate 18.04, kubuntu 18.04, xubuntu 18.04, and a live ubuntu 20.10) this is what I get after
`lspci | grep VGA`:
*01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC410M [Mobility Radeon Xpress **200M**]*

But it's not true, my graphic card is *ATI Radeon Xpress **1100***.

Also,    `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'` gives:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC410M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200M]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RC410M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200M]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeonfb, radeon
```

I am sure it's Ati Radeon Xpress 1100 as that is in the stick label and also with windows.

### Can I make Ubuntu see it?

As a "workaround", I even tried (in all 4 ubuntus) to get proprietary drivers from the "Software and updates" app, in the "Additional Drivers" tab; what I get is that there is no driver needed.

**Later on I might try a manual install as [here](https://drivers.amd.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf) from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04), but for now maybe there is a way for ubuntu to correctly identify my graphic card.**

I also have downloaded the corresponding Linux driver from AMD site [the one for Linux x86_64 from this page](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/integrated-motherboard-graphics/ati-radeon-xpress-series/ati-radeon-xpress-1100), but if I open the file (ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run) in an elevated Terminal emulator, after the archive is uncompressed, it writes:

```
Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version
default:v2:x86_64:lib::none:5.4.0-42-generic; make sure that the version is being
correctly set by --iscurrentdistro

Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.8ncUac
```

Also strange is that command:

```
sudo ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg xubuntu/bionic
```

gives: "sudo: ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run: command not found
"

Comment: Regarding `fglrx-install.8ncUac` — Watch out, the fglrx type drivers (together with "Catalyst control center") are not compatible with Ubuntu any more (they were irrelevant already as long back as 16.04). This is true at least for when your display server is Xorg. I don't know what's the deal in this regard with Wayland.

Comment: There is not a driver for that graphics card for any version of Ubuntu past 14.04. Drivers are built into the kernel now for that card.

Comment: @Eagle_Mike yeah, but the kernel-built-in driver (open source radeon?) identifies the card incorrectly. Can anything be done with that?

Comment: @Eagle_Mike Does that mean that Ubuntu 14.04 would list and use it correctly? It's in extended support, I don't need anything fancy, but a little more GPU performance may be welcomed.

Comment: @Dan could you edit your question and include what `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'` says? It's an extended variant which will also identify the driver you use.

Comment: @Levente done, it's updated

Comment: Dan, it's using the only thing available, the driver embedded in the kernel. The driver which would be installed in 14.04 is old (as is 14.04) and has been replaced by code in the kernel. Your GPU is a variant of  what your system is reporting and the kernel probably uses the same code for all similar GPU variants.

Comment: @Eagle_Mike sad thing is, this approximation is not always satisfactory. I am [in a similar situation](https://askubuntu.com/a/1304633/1157519) and I can testify that the open source radeon driver — even though it attempts an approximate identification of my card — is of no help at all (programs crash / don't even start with it). That's why it would be nice to be able to override / supply suggestions on how the driver should interact with the card.